# Prevent Jupyter from switching between normal mathematical notation and scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I want to ask a question about turning off scientific notation of numbers in Jupyter notebook.

I have an array named `my_array` that shows the following when called:

```
my_array
---------
array([[1.63276953e+02, 1.41858314e-01],
   [1.64042353e+02, 5.13131094e-01]])
```

and I would like to display this in normal form i.e.

```
array([[163.27... , 0.141... ],
   [164.04... , 0.513...]])
```

I am using `pylab` (otherwise also known as `matplotlib`) and `numpy` and have imported it as such:

```
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
```

I have tried to solve this solution using such a method given here in another question but this involves panda and not either of the modules mentioned above.

How can I suppress scientific notation here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `numpy` print issue:

```
In [544]: with np.printoptions(suppress=True): 
     ...:     np.array([[1.63276953e+02, 1.41858314e-01], 
     ...:    [1.64042353e+02, 5.13131094e-01]]) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [545]: with np.printoptions(suppress=True): 
     ...:    print( np.array([[1.63276953e+02, 1.41858314e-01], 
     ...:    [1.64042353e+02, 5.13131094e-01]])) 
     ...:     
     ...:                                                                                      
[[163.276953     0.14185831]
 [164.042353     0.51313109]]

In [546]: with np.printoptions(suppress=False): 
     ...:    print( np.array([[1.63276953e+02, 1.41858314e-01], 
     ...:    [1.64042353e+02, 5.13131094e-01]])) 
     ...:     
     ...:                                                                                      
[[1.63276953e+02 1.41858314e-01]
 [1.64042353e+02 5.13131094e-01]]
```

`np.set_printoptions` can be used to change this (and other) options for the session/script.